# Is there any way to assign weight to historical data while fitting a topic model on text documents?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, gensim, topic-modeling

I am performing topic modeling on year-on-year textual data. While fitting the model, I want to assign less weight to older documents and more weight to recent documents, so the topics are more in line with what is present in recent texts. Particularly, is there a technically correct way to do this using libraries like Gensim and Scikit-Learn?

Answer (score 0):

You could try overweighting the influence of some documents by synthetically expanding their text: either turning the single document into the same text repeated 2 (or more) times, or simply repeating the whole document as a separate document.

(In that latter case, the replicas of a document are likely to have their best influence if spaced throughout the training set, rather than simply repeated N times in a row.)